# How to find example of app: scala + play 2.4 + extJs 5 + auth

Tags: scala, extjs, playframework, silhouette

Where can i get examples of application template:
scala + play framework 2.4 + extJs 5 + silhouette.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look at the activator templates provided by typesafe, i.e: [The Play Silhouette Seed Project](http://www.typesafe.com/activator/template/play-silhouette-seed)